# Java Programming using Objects/ Methods

Tags: java

I am having trouble getting the balance after a deposit and withdraw to stay, instead it goes back to the initial balance and does the operation.

I ask it to withdraw 2500, which should leave me with 17500, but then I have it do a deposit for 3000, which should give me 20500, but instead I get 23000.

Also, I keep getting "null" for my date output.

This is the first Class file.

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Account
{
   private int id;
   private double balance;
   private double annualInterestRate;
   private Date dateCreated;
   private double withdraw;
   private double deposit;

   Account()
   {
      id = 1;
      balance = 1;
      annualInterestRate = 1;
   }

   Account(int newID, double newBalance, double newAnnualInterestRate)
   {
      id = newID;
      balance = newBalance;
      annualInterestRate = newAnnualInterestRate;   
   }

   public int getId()
   {
      return id;
   }

   public double getBalance()
   {
      return balance;
   }

   public double getAnnualInterestRate()
   {
      return annualInterestRate;
   }

   public double getMonthlyInterestRate()
   {
      return (annualInterestRate / 12) / 100;
   }

   public double getMonthlyInterest()
   {
      return balance * getMonthlyInterestRate();
   }

   public double getWithdraw(double amount)
   {
      amount = balance - amount;
      return amount;
   }

   public double getDeposit(double amount)
   {
      amount = balance + amount;
      return amount;
   }

   public Date getDateCreated()
   {
      return dateCreated;
   }
}
```

This is the test class file

```
public class TestAccount
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Account A = new Account(1122, 20000, 4.5);

      System.out.println("Account number: " + A.getId());
      System.out.println("The Account balance is: $" + A.getBalance() + "0");
      System.out.println("The Annual Interest Rate is: " + A.getAnnualInterestRate()+ "%");
      System.out.println("The Account balance after a $2,500 withrawal is: " + A.getWithdraw(2500));
      System.out.println("The Account balance after a $3,000 deposit is: " + A.getDeposit(3000));
      System.out.println("The monthly interest earned is: " + A.getMonthlyInterest());
      System.out.println("The account was created on: " + A.getDateCreated());   
   }
}
```

Comment: That is probably the worlds's most vague title ever...

Answer (score 3):

You are modifying the local variable `amount`, instead of modifying `balance`.  In `getWithdraw`, change

```
amount = balance - amount;
```

to

```
balance = balance - amount;
```

and likewise for the `getDeposit` method.

Incidentally, it's unclear why you are calling those methods `getWithdraw` and `getDeposit`, since those methods make withdrawals and deposits, respectively.  I would have called them `withdraw` and `deposit`.   I also find no purpose to returning the parameter value `amount` in both methods.  Both methods don't need to return anything and can be specified to return `void`.

Also, nothing is ever assigned to `dateCreated`, so it's `null`.  You can add a setter method for this instance variable.

Comment: Good answer. I would also suggest renaming the getDeposit() and getWithdraw() methods. It is a useful convention that methods whose name starts with get not have side effects.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't see that, Thanks! Such a simple fix, what about the date print out? I keep getting null?

Comment: @CPTKirk I've added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I made the recommended changes and it works like a charm now.

Answer (score 1):

In your `getWithdraw` and `getDeposit` methods, you probably should be changing the `balance`, not the `amount`. There's also no reason to return the `amount` from these methods.

You never create a `Date` object anywhere that I can see, so your date is `null`. Based on the name of the `getDateCreated` method, I'm guessing that the date should be set to the date that the account was created, so you should do that in your `Account` constructor.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about having that object!